# How to get the $U$ in the bottom of the diagram below $\Phi$?

Tags: commutative-diagrams

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$U\times \mathbb{R}^k$};
\node[below=of F] (A) {$U$};

\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] {$\Phi$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A) node [midway,below] {$\pi$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A) node [midway,right] {$\pi_1$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Also how to get a circular arrow(diagram commutes indicator) in the triangle.

Comment: [You mean like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Chpuo.png). Also, what do you mean by "circular arrow(diagram commutes indicator) in the triangle". Can you show some picture as to from where to where you want circular arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I understood the question properly but with help from  Torbjørn things started clearing out. It may be like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$U\times \mathbb{R}^k$};

\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] (phi) {$\Phi$};
\node[below= 1cm of phi] (A) {$U$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A.north west) node [midway,below] {$\pi$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A.north east) node [midway,right] {$\pi_1$};
\draw [<-] ([yshift=2mm]A.north) arc[start angle=-90,delta angle=350,radius=0.3cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For diagrams like this `tikz-cd` offers a friendly syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}%[column sep=large]
   E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ]& & U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
      &  U &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And I have not understood the circular part totally.

Comment: I guess it's a `\draw [->] (x,y) arc[start angle=0,delta angle=270,radius=0.2cm];` inside the triangle he's after. And the question title was changed now, the U should be below the Phi, i.e. centered horizontally relative to the two elements in the first row.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. it was really helpful as I was blind here. :-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., nice catch. :)